# Diagonally merge two column into one with different color background

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm currently building an HTML/CSS table that shows values and colors each cell with either red/yellow/green or grey/white, according to some underlying logic.

Problem now is, that some columns need to be merged - including their different colors being diagonally split, i.e. like this:

[image]

While I can easily color the normal cells, I'm still looking for a elegant solution for the split cells. The only idea I have so far is to use background picture for each color combination. However, I'm wondering if there's a better, native-CSS solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with pseudo elements and css triangles.

Like so:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ZscpE/1/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="top">50%</div>
    <div class="bottom">40%</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.cell
{
    width: 100px;
    height:40px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.bottom
{
    text-align: right;
}
.cell div:before
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid; 
    z-index: -1;
}
.top:before
{ 

    border-width: 40px 100px 0 0;
    border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;
}
.bottom:before
{
    border-width: 0 0 40px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
    top:1px;
    left:1px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this would be possible using this method of css triangles  because we are messing with the border-width not the actual width property.. so swapping the px value of the border-width to 100% won't work. So if you need cells to expand according to text - at this stage i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: On the other hand: say you have different-sized cols but each of which with a known fixed width - then some css preprocessing could come in handy (using say LESS or SASS) where you could set up variables for the different width cols

Comment: makes sense, thanks! Let's see if fixed width will fly with the client and if not I'll go for a few pre-defined widths using SASS...